# Static type checking in Python: Conflicting alternatives?

Tags: python, static-typing

Today I was introduced to multiple ways of using static type checking in Python (by the [the Coconut tutorial](http://coconut.readthedocs.io/en/master/HELP.html)). It lists [python 3.5 type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), [python 3.6 variable annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), and [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/). I then found another, from Google, called [pytype](https://github.com/google/pytype).

Do these alternatives conflict? Does any of them rely on any of the others? Does any (subset) of them render any of the others unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

The first three options you've mentioned are related. Type-hints introduced in Python 3.5 (as a consequence of [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) and supported by Python 2.7 (via stub-files) were inspired by the MyPy project. The whole system is now being developed alongside MyPy. Variable type-hints introduced in Python 3.6 are a part of the process: they are perfectly consistent with never MyPy releases. pytype seems to be an alternative static analyser created for the same type-hint system. In other words, MyPy and pytype are designed for the same type-system.